# How to arrange elements in a modal in two column layout using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a UI on which there is a button on clicking the button, I display the following modal:

```
<div class="modal myModal" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 align="center" class="modal-title">Title</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body" layout="row" layout-wrap>
                <div id="table_data" flex="50">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Col1</th>
                            <th>Col2</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ng-repeat="item in myList" ng-if=myList>
                            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.type}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <div id="tabbed_data" flex="50">
                    <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#tab1"
                                            data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="tab-content">
                            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1">
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2">
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code displays the modal, but the two divs are stacked one on top of the other.

I am trying to make it into a two column layout such that within the modal window, the `<div id="table_data">` is displayed on the left and the `<div id="table_data">` is displayed on the right with equal width for each column.

I am using the following to arrange it in proper columns: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout

But, the row layout doesn't seem to be working.

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Are you displaying the model with mdDialog or some other modal?

Comment: for showing the modal, I have a function on button click: $scope.showModal() and within that, I just use $('#myModal').modal('show');

Comment: Ok, you're not really using angular material at all. I really don't know if you can just mix its flexbox implementation with other things. If you want to use Angular Material, then I'd recommend that you look at the mdDialog service, which can do what you want easily. It's best practice to try to avoid mixing jQuery style coding into your angular app.

Comment: Thanks, I will check that out... also, is there some other way to achieve this, without the mdDialog service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got this to work and I thought I'd post the answer in case someone is stuck in a similar situation:

This is how I did it:

```
<div class="modal myModal" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 align="center" class="modal-title">Title</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="table_data" class="col-md-6">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Col1</th>
                                <th>Col2</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr ng-repeat="item in myList" ng-if=myList>
                                <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                                <td>{{item.type}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                    <div id="tabbed_data" class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                                    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1"
                                            data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1">
                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2">
                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```